# MySQL to show the max and min days for a distinct third value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to out put a max and min date/time for each week.  there are multiple entries in my table for each week.

Here is some example date

```
Week   Date
1      2013-02-01 10:10:23
1      2013-04-12 09:23:00
1      2013-04-13 12:23:00
2      2013-01-21 08:10:00
2      2013-04-12 09:23:45
2      2013-04-12 03:33:12
```

The output I am looking for is

```
week         Max Date              Min Date
1         2013-04-13 12:23:00        2013-02-01 10:10:23
2         2013-04-12 09:23:45        2013-01-21 08:10:00
```

Any help on where too begin would be great.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an aggregate function with a GROUP BY. This applies both the `min()` and `max()` aggregates to the date column and groups by the `week`:

```
select week,
  max(date) max_date,
  min(date) mind_date
from yourtable
group by week;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bf94/1)

Comment: Thank you.. this is exactly what I needed.  And thanks for sharing SQL Fiddle.. Haven't seen that before.  It will definitely come in handy.